# Moodle - Zoho CRM Integration

Tags: moodle, zoho

Anybody had any experience or know of a way of integrating Moodle with Zoho CRM? Can't find a plug-in. Would like to be able to sync the two of them. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such a plugin. I've only found [this article](http://scottweidig.com/2008/04/05/down-the-rabbit-hole-and-into-the-wonders-of-zoho/) where the author explains how he uses Moodle and Zoho together.